# Rails STI vs Polymorphic vs Neither

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance, sti

I have a Users class in my rails app.  I need two types of users, 1) Players, 2) Managers.  Users will all log in using Devise and have same basic user fields.  I will have a League model.  What is the best way to model this?  STI doesn't seem quite right but not sure if Polymorphic works either since if both Manager < User && Player < User.  The only real role a manager will have will be admin roles such as adding/removing players from leagues, setting up schedules etc.

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :manager
  has_many :players

end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  belongs_to :league
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leagues
end

class Player < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leagues
  has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
end

class Manager < User
  has_many :leagues
end
```

Any suggestions for the best way to set this up are greatly appreciated!
Using STI for players ActiveRecord is looking for Player table for the join but it doesn't exist.

Comment: why do you think STI is not right, is there any different database attributes between player, manager ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STI can work for this, but since the difference between the types of users is basically a flag that says a user is an admin, you just need something on a user to check whether they are allowed certain actions. Roles can be either exclusive or inclusive (so that a user can be both a Player and a Manager), but once set up you can shape the interface around the capabilities a user has:

```
<% if @user.has_role?('manager') %>
  <%= render 'manager_fields' # or manager_page, etc. %>
<% end %>
```

How you handle this in the controller depends on how you implement the roles, either via gems like Pundit, CanCanCan, etc. or through explicit checks in something you write yourself. The gems will give you helper methods to reduce the amount of typing involved in views and a more declarative syntax on the back end.

Comment: thanks!  User will be Player and/or Manger.  If a user creates a league, he will be Manager of that league by default.  Only Manager can edit league information, perhaps control who joins the league etc.  I like the idea of Roles.  But not sure the easiest or best way to implement.  I will check out CanCanCan but I'd like to keep it simple.  Admin will only be for lower system level admin, not managers or players (both regular users).

Comment: In that case it would be simpler to create a separate association between users and leagues, `belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'` on League and leave the users alone. You can then check `@league.manager`.

Comment: That seems simple enough.  What else would I need in migration? type field in Users?

Comment: Oh no, not at all. I'm guessing you already have an association between Users (Players) and Team/Leagues, so just add `:manager_id` to League, add the above association definition, and you can assign a user as manager by typing `@league.manager = @user`, create a league through `League.new(:manager => current_user)` and so on.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much for your help!  Last question... If I wanted to refer to Users as Players throughout app am I just making my life more difficult?  So far everything else is working. I had originally tried STI but that seemed to cause more complexity/problems.

Comment: As I work more on this application it seems to actually make sense to use STI.  It would also seem more accurate to be able to do @league.players instead of @league.users .  I'm close except when I try to do @league.players << @player I'm getting:  ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `player_id`

Comment: You can configure League so it `has_many :players, class_name: 'User'`, then @league will only ever have players and a manager. User will just be the Model name, though without STI you would query based on User as well: `@player = User.find(...)`

Answer (score 1):

STI eliminates the need of separate tables for each class, given that most (or ideally all) attributes are shared between the two models.
In this case we'd add a new column in the users table called `type` which will indicate the class that this record will be parsed to, so either `Player` or `Manager`
As for the models

```
class Player < User
```

and

```
class Manager < User
```

As for the permission you could check if the user instance is of type `Player` or `Manager`

Of course you don't need to do STI if you don't want to, instead you'll create two tables `players` and `managers` and you'll need to join them with the `User` model, which would be tricky, since not all users have managers and not all users have players, so one or the other will always return nil, .. unless you create a polymorphic relation, but then you'll need to check the type of the object, .. idk

I think STI is your best solution, for the time being

Comment: you haven't really answered my question or told me anything I didn't already know.  I'm trying to go with STI at this point, but I'm doing something wrong with my migrations.  I can seem to add players to matches.

Comment: When I do league1.players << player1 I get error: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `league_id`

Comment: Yes, both.  I'm trying still with STI but still it's not so simple Now League is looking for leauges_players join table but there is no Player table with STI.  I've researched this and seems like an inherent problem with STI and ActiveRecord.

Comment: could you add the user and manager model definitions to the question